# Stop method from executing on button press

Tags: android

I have written a menu for an application with multiple buttons. Two of these buttons trigger two separate Bluetooth methods. The problem is that on multiple quick presses of these buttons the app crashes because each method is attempting to manage the Bluetooth connection (while another may close that connection). I have tried setting a variable 'true' while any of the methods is running and checking for that but it does not work. I am unsure of whether the system runs each method concurrently in different threads or if it enqueues the methods .

The question is how exactly do I stop a button press to run a method while another method is executing? I don't need it enqueued after the executing one finishes, I only need it blocked.

EDIT: Added code of one of the methods below, as requested (the other one is identical, with the exception of two strings, which are irrelevant in this context):

```
public void lock(View button_lock) {
        if(ok)
            return;
        if (btAdapter == null) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Bluetooth not supported!";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
            return;
        }
        else if (address == null) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Please pair your phone with SmartLock.";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
            return;
        }
        if (!btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            btAdapter.enable();
            ok=true;
        }
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {public void run() {
            BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
            ParcelUuid[] uuids = device.getUuids();
            BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
            try {
                mmSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuids[0].getUuid());
                mmSocket.connect();
                OutputStream out = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
                InputStream in = mmSocket.getInputStream();
                out.write("1".getBytes());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                in.close();
                out.close();
                mmSocket.close();
                in = null;
                out = null;
                mmSocket = null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }}, 1000);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Bike locked!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            btAdapter.disable();
            ok=false;
        }}, 2000);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already tried it with a boolean, a [semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) could do the trick here.

Answer (score 1):

You can't solve this problem by disabling the button in `onClick()`, because of the way Android's event system works. When the user presses the button, a "click" event is queued to the event queue. If the user presses the button twice in rapid succession (especially on low-end devices or when the UI thread is busy), 2 "click" events will be inserted into the queue. You cannot prevent this.

What you need to do is to remember that you've processed the "click" event and ignore any that arrive after that (until you want to allow the user to click again). It sounds like you have already tried this. Please post your code so we can see what is wrong.

---

After seeing your code I have the following input:

If `mHandler` has been created on the main (UI) thread, you have a problem You have code here that is doing network I/O and sleeping. You absolutely can not do that on the main (UI) thread. Make sure this stuff is running in a background thread. To do this, either create your own `Thread` or make sure that your `Handler` is created on a background thread (see `HandlerThread` as one example).

Before you call `postDelayed()`, set a boolean variable `running` to `true`. This flag should be cleared to `false` when the posted `Runnable` completes. To make sure of this, wrap your whole `run()` method in a `try/catch` and clear the variable in a `finally` block.

In `lock()`, first check if the boolean variable `running` is `true`. If it is, you should just return immediately, which will ignore click events that occur when you aren't ready for them.

Comment: The boolean `ok` is supposed to serve the same purpose as the `running` you proposed.

Comment: Then I don't understand the problem. Please explain what is crashing and what Exception you get and what isn't working.

Comment: Also, you are posting 2 `Runnable`s. One should run after 1 second, the next after 2 seconds. This isn't good because you don't know how long the first `Runnable` will run. Better would be the first `Runnable` should post the second `Runnable` when it completes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    bluetoothMethod();
    bluetoothButton.setEnabled(false);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            bluetoothButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }, duration);
```

(duration in milis)

Comment: This does not fix the issue, only delays the action, it a bad way to deal with this, see @Patrick Michel answer for a better way to deal with it